Проблема с NULL в файле main.py
Работал над одним кодом и в процессе вырубился ноут, тк села зарядка, зарядил его только на следующий день дома. В результате в файле main.py моего проекта все символы сменились на NULL. Проблема в том, что файл лежал на флешке и восстановить прошлую версию не выходит. Может ктто-то сталкивался с таким?

Пробуйте тупо проверку диска сделать, но не гарантирую что это как-то поможет. Сталкиваться-то сталкивались, но итог один - не хранить важное на одном ненадежном носителе. На будущее может помочь форматирование флешки в NTFS (если она у вас вдруг форматирована в FAT32), настроить в системе быстрое извлечение флешек (без необходимости "безопасного извлечения"), тогда информация не будет кэшироваться перед записью, некоторые операции будут работать медленнее, но будет меньше шансов, что информация будет испорчена при нештатном выключении.
